# Mongoid does not complain if I insert a object with duplicate _id

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I have a Sinatra/Mongoid application and I noticed that my mongoid model/object does not complain or error out if I try to insert a duplicate `_id` object. The `object.errors` collection is empty as well.

"Object/record is not inserted."

On Mongo console I do get a "duplicate key error index" error.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo updates/inserts are somewhat "fire&forget" by default. You can however turn on [safe mode](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/safe_mode.html) which should raise errors when this sort of stuff happens